# How can I enlarge my iframe keeping the aspect ratio?

Tags: html, css, iframe

I try to enlarge my embedded youtube video but it is not resizing. How should I do it? My HTML is

```
<div class="mainContent post ">

            <div class="paragraphs">

                    <div class="post-content"><div class="post-content-inner"><iframe width="512" height="288" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/r9yH-EmnGX4?feature=oembed" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen"></iframe></div></div>

            </div>
        </div>
```

My CSS which is not working is

```
.mainContent{

    max-width: 700px;/*for example*/

}

.paragraphs{

    max-width: 700px;/*for example*/

}

.post-content{

    max-width: 700px;/*for example*/

}
.post-content-inner {
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 56.25%; /*288/512=0.5625*/
    height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.post-content-inner iframe{
    position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Can you help me so that the iframe is enlarged to fill the div?

Comment: Could you perhaps create a fiddle to demonstrate what you're meaning exactly?

Answer (score 0):

Well the iframe is taking the size of the parent div. If the top parent div gets bigger so does the iframe. So if you set the main content to a specific size and use percentage on the sub divs it should resize accordingly. You can check it in this fiddle by just changing the width of the maincontent in the css:
http://jsfiddle.net/rwybp41e/8/

```
.mainContent{

    width: 1200px;/*modify here for resize*/

}

.paragraphs{

    width: 100%;/*!*/

}

.post-content{

    max-width: 100%;/*!*/

}
.post-content-inner {
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 56.25%; /*288/512=0.5625*/
    height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.post-content-inner iframe{
    position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks but is it possible to make the size of the video also shrink when the parent window is shrunk? This solution works for enlarging the video but it can't shrink the video if the window is shrunk. Maybe this is another separate question distinct from my original question.

Comment: Well if you decrease the maincontent width the video shrinks too. I thought this is what you wanted. Maybe it is better to give an example of what you want.

Comment: I have it working on one page but not on this one because it is too complicated. I don't know how to set the size of the parent div to relative. The video either becomes too small (default size) or, when the page is shrunk, becomes too large and is clipped to the right of the video. I don't know why this is not easy and I think that the whole design of fluid 7 responsive is a complete mess making something easy extremely difficult.